# Rewrite image directory to another folder in server using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have images in

```
/home/crawler/scrapers/images/website
```

for example

```
/home/crawler/scrapers/images/website/1/img-name.jpg
```

My Apache root is at

```
/var/www/html
```

I have `.htaccess` in this folder with following content

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/images/(.*)$ /home/crawler/scrapers/images/$1 [R,L]
```

My goal is to show images from the images folder as I mentioned above.

```
http://website.com/images/website/1/img-name.jpg   >>  /home/crawler/scrapers/images/website/1/img-name.jpg
```

Currently I am getting

```
Not Found

The requested URL /home/crawler/scrapers/images/website/1/img-name.jpg was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at IP Port 80
```

**PS:** I confirm that hataccess is enabled.

Comment: You cannot access files outside your `DocumentRoot`. Do you have control over Apache config?

Comment: @anubhava yes i have control on everything. It's a dedicated ubuntu server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Alias` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) for this.

Include following code in your `vhosts.conf` or `httpd.conf` and restart Apache.

```
Alias /images /home/crawler/scrapers/images
<Directory /home/crawler/scrapers/images>
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```